# Jquery hover event not repeating

Tags: jquery, hover, transition, opacity

I want to repeat the `opacity transition` in each `hover`. Can anyone help me?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".item1").hover(function(){
        $('.mask1').css({"visibility":"visible","opacity":"1"});
    }, 
    function(){
        $('.mask1').css("visibility", "hidden");
    });
```

Comment: $('.mask1').css({"visibility":"hidden","opacity":"0"});

Comment: Did you try adding `"opacity":"0"` in the second part of the `hover` definition?

Comment: yes css i write is correct, i just want to apply a continues effect for the div in each hover

Answer (score 0):

Use toggle() function instead ...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".item1").hover(function(){
        $('.mask1').toggle(); // if hidden, show it... if shown, hide it...
    });
```

Comment: this is  just a hover effect on a image . why should i use a toggle .. i could not understand

Comment: If you want to use hide and show your image, that's how it works in jQuery